# xticklabel distance for math expression

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I have a `pgfplot` and the labels in the `x axis` are not centered as I expected and this is because one of them is higher than the other because of the superscript.

```
\documentclass[]{article}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ytick={\empty},
            ytick={},
            xticklabels={$u_{n+1}^{}$,$u_{n+1}^{0}$},
            xtick={0,4},
            yticklabels={$r(u_{n+1}^{}) = 0$,$r(u_{n+1}^{0})>0$},
            ytick={-2,2},
            domain=-2:6,
            samples=55,
            scaled ticks=false,
            ymax=10,
            ymin=-5,
            xtick distance={60},
            ]
            %\addplot+[no marks,thick] {-5*(x-1)*(x)*(x-2)};
            \addplot[smooth,thick]
                coordinates{
                    (-1.9,9.9) (-1,0) (0,-2) 
                    (1,0)(3,4)(4,2)
                    (5,4)(6,10)
                };
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:0,-5) -- (axis cs:0,-2);
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:4,-5) -- (axis cs:4,2);
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-3,-2) -- (axis cs:0,-2);
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-3,2) -- (axis cs:4,2);
            \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,scale=0.8] at (axis cs:0,-2) {};
            \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,scale=0.8] at (axis cs:4,2) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a zoom of the axis:

[image]

How can I do to center the letter `u` to the same distance ?

Comment: Just add `xticklabel style={text height=2ex},`.

Comment: It has not worked :( I tried also with `20ex` and I see no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine adding `xticklabel style={text height=2ex}` works.

```
\documentclass[]{article}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ytick={\empty},
            ytick={},
            xticklabels={$u_{n+1}^{}$,$u_{n+1}^{0}$},
            xtick={0,4},
            yticklabels={$r(u_{n+1}^{}) = 0$,$r(u_{n+1}^{0})>0$},
            xticklabel style={text height=2ex},
            ytick={-2,2},
            domain=-2:6,
            samples=55,
            scaled ticks=false,
            ymax=10,
            ymin=-5,
            xtick distance={60},
            ]
            %\addplot+[no marks,thick] {-5*(x-1)*(x)*(x-2)};
            \addplot[smooth,thick]
                coordinates{
                    (-1.9,9.9) (-1,0) (0,-2) 
                    (1,0)(3,4)(4,2)
                    (5,4)(6,10)
                };
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:0,-5) -- (axis cs:0,-2);
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:4,-5) -- (axis cs:4,2);
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-3,-2) -- (axis cs:0,-2);
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-3,2) -- (axis cs:4,2);
            \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,scale=0.8] at (axis cs:0,-2) {};
            \node[circle,draw=black,fill=black,scale=0.8] at (axis cs:4,2) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, sorry I was doing something wrong, now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this there exists the option `typeset ticklabels with strut`. Simply add it to the `axis` options and you receive the expected result.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick={0,4},
        xticklabels={$u_{n+1}^{}$,$u_{n+1}^{0}$},
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=10,
        ytick={-2,2},
        yticklabels={$r(u_{n+1}^{}) = 0$,$r(u_{n+1}^{0})>0$},
        typeset ticklabels with strut,      % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot [smooth,thick] coordinates {
            (-1.9,9.9) (-1,0) (0,-2)
            (1,0)(3,4)(4,2)
            (5,4)(6,10)
        };
        \draw [dashed] (axis cs:0,-5) -- (axis cs:0,-2);
        \draw [dashed] (axis cs:4,-5) -- (axis cs:4,2);
        \draw [dashed] (axis cs:-3,-2) -- (axis cs:0,-2);
        \draw [dashed] (axis cs:-3,2) -- (axis cs:4,2);
        \node [circle,draw=black,fill=black,scale=0.8] at (axis cs:0,-2) {};
        \node [circle,draw=black,fill=black,scale=0.8] at (axis cs:4,2) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]